# Test if Flask response is JSON

Tags: python, flask

How can I test that the response a Flask view generated is JSON?

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify(message='hello world')

c = app.app.test_client()
assert c.get('/').status_code == 200
# assert is json
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Flask 1.0, `response.get_json()` will parse the response data as JSON or raise an error.

```
response = c.get("/")
assert response.get_json()["message"] == "hello world"
```

---

`jsonify` sets the content type to `application/json`. Additionally, you can try parsing the response data as JSON. If it fails to parse, your test will fail.

```
from flask import json
assert response.content_type == 'application/json'
data = json.loads(response.get_data(as_text=True))
assert data['message'] == 'hello world'
```

Typically, this test on its own doesn't make sense. You know it's JSON since `jsonify` returned without error, and `jsonify` is already tested by Flask. If it was not valid JSON, you would have received an error while serializing the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python-library for it.

```
import json
#...
def checkJson(s):
    try:
        json.decode(s)
        return True
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        return False
```

If you also want to check if it is a valid string, check the boundaries for "s.
You can read the help here on pythons website https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html .